# How to make the size of the input the size of the placeholder?

Tags: html, css, input

I don't know if you understand my issue.

I have a form that takes as input an ip or a dns name and I want my input to be the size of my placeholder

How can I do this ?

Comment: Add Some Code here

Comment: Do you mean the width of the input field or the allowed amount of characters the user can input?

Comment: Yes, width of the input = width of the placeholder

Comment: Please read [ask], and how to post your code as a [mcve] before posting a question. When you're ready to post your code
⏩[look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪